# how to create preact-cli custom production build

Tags: javascript, preact

I'm now studying `preact-cli` and so far, it's working though. Problem is when we're gonna build for production, there is zero-configuration for it and found no works for api caching. Is there anyone who has had experience about it, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes, all the config based settings for `preact-cli` goes inside `preact.config.js`.

you have multiple plugins to support this : https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/wiki/Plugins

You can do runtime caching of API's using `service workers` and [preact-cli-sw-precache](https://github.com/prateekbh/preact-cli-sw-precache).